# Gerrit push not working. Remote rejected, prohibited by gerrit

Tags: git, github, ssh, gerrit

I am trying to add an existing repo to gerrit. I create an empty project and have tried pushing it (`git push ssh://admin@localhost:29418/project *:*`). I get this error message in return:

```
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 384 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 3 (delta 1)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 3, done    
To ssh://admin@localhost:29418/project
 ! [remote rejected] origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD (prohibited by Gerrit)
 ! [remote rejected] origin/master -> origin/master (prohibited by Gerrit)
 ! [remote rejected] origin/ref/for/master/testing -> origin/ref/for/master/testing (prohibited by Gerrit)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://admin@localhost:29418/project'
```

I have already gone to the gerrit site and under `project/access` added `refs/head/*` Create Reference privileges for all users.

Comment: I assume that you are able to use gerrit normally (ie, creating changes and merging them) and just are having trouble with direct pushing?

Answer (score 9):

From my experience you need the following group permissions to import an entire repository to gerrit -- basically permissions to push everything to the gerrit repo:

- refs/heads/*

  - create reference
  - forge author identity
  - forge committer identity
  - push
  - push merge commit
  - push annotated tag
- refs/tags/*

  - create reference

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding the Create Reference privilege, you will also need to ensure that you have the direct push/force push privilege--creating a reference would involve creating a new branch, whereas updating an existing branch (namely, `origin/HEAD` and `origin/master`) will require the direct push/force push privilege (I have seen gerrit refer to this as both direct push and force push in the documentation).

Comment: so i added force push privileges for users and still i get an (prohibited by gerrit) error when pushing origin/HEAD and origin/master remotes

Answer (score 0):

in your git project ,use git config --list  to see your user.name,user.email is or not equal to your local gerrit site user's name or email.They must be same.if not equal, use git config user.name XXX.

at last.  git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
so you can use git push origin master